# How to jump to an HTML page from Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In Silverlight, I can use

> System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Navigate("url");

to navigate to an HTML page.
I'm trying to do the same from a Lightswitch application, but I don't know how to get a hold of the HtmlPage (say, from inside my custom window that derives from

> Microsoft.LightSwitch.Runtime.Shell.Framework.ScreenChildWindow

, or from a global command that derives from

> Microsoft.LightSwitch.Runtime.Shell.ViewModels.Commands

).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Switch to **File View**
2. Add a reference in the **Client** project to **System.Windows.Browser**
3. In the modal window's code, or in the command's code, use **HtmlPage.Navigate("url_of_html_page")**

Here's a sample that uses the same method: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Add-URL-To-LightSwitchs-0f74eef4